# UPDATE not capturing changes to or from NULL

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I create a table in which there is an element, `parentId`, that is linked via a `FOREIGN KEY` to another `uniqueId` of the same table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE folders (
    uniqueId         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name             TEXT    NOT NULL,
    parentId         INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
    created          TEXT    DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime')),
    updated          TEXT    DEFAULT (datetime('now', 'localtime')),
    FOREIGN KEY (parentId)
        REFERENCES folders (uniqueId) 
        ON DELETE    SET DEFAULT
);
```

I also have a `TRIGGER` that will set the `updated` field to the current time upon modifying the `parentId` field.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER folder_parentId_is_changed
    AFTER UPDATE ON folders
    WHEN new.parentId <> old.parentId
BEGIN
    UPDATE folders
        SET updated = datetime('now','localtime')
        WHERE parentId = new.parentId;
END;
```

If the `parentId` has a non-`NULL` value, and I change the `parentId` to another non-`NULL` value, the `TRIGGER` works as I desire, and the `updated` field is set to current time.
*However*, `TRIGGER` does not capture changes to or from `NULL`. That is, if the `parentId` is currently `NULL` and I change it so that `parentId == 5`, the `TRIGGER` will not update my `update` field.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your query.

First, the condition:

```
WHEN new.parentId <> old.parentId
```

will not work if either of `new.parentId` or `old.parentId` is `null`, because the result of the comparison with the operator `<>` will be `null` and will never be `true`.
So you must use [`IS NOT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#operators) instead of `<>`, which will work for `null`s and not `null`s.

Also, the condition in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
WHERE parentId = new.parentId
```

is wrong, because it may return all the rows where `parentId` is equal to `new.parentId`, or none if `new.parentId` is `null`.
Instead you should set a condition that returns the row that you want to update based on the column `uniqueId` which is the primary key of the table and will return only the row that is updated:

```
CREATE TRIGGER folder_parentId_is_changed
AFTER UPDATE ON folders
WHEN NEW.parentId IS NOT OLD.parentId
BEGIN
    UPDATE folders
    SET updated = DATETIME('now', 'localtime')
    WHERE uniqueId = OLD.uniqueId;
END;
```